# Vim - Map alternate key behavior depending on context

Tags: vim

I have my column numbers set to relative mode because I like not counting. 
I also have `nnoremap`ped `j` to `gj` so that it's easier to work with line wraps. The problem is that when I do a motion (say `2j`) on a line that's wrapped, it doesn't move me up two rows, but two "lines".

In order to fix that, I would like to have `j` mapped to `gj` for regular movement, but act like regular `j` when given `count`. I have tried the following command in my `vimrc`:

```
"  Up and down now don't skip line-wraps unless given count
fun! MoveLines( lines, type )
    if ( a:lines == 1 )
        let a:str = 'g' . a:type
    else
        let a:str = a:lines . a:type
    endif
    call feedkeys( a:str )
endfun

nnoremap <silent> j :<C-U>call MoveLines( v:count1, 'j' )<CR>
```

This works fine when I just press `j`. The problem is when I try to give it a count: it calls itself recursively (as would be expected). I could try using `cursor`, but is it possible to do it without this way?

How can I conditionally map `j` to act as `gj` when not given a count, but act like normal when given a count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `v:count` to get the current count given. If nothing is provided it is set to zero.

```
nnoremap <expr> j v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j'
```

For more help see:

```
:h v:count
:h :map-<expr>
```

Comment: I knew there was an easier way! So much better; thanks